# How to limit number of fields received json can hold?

Tags: postgresql, go

I am building a web server in Go that receives JSON and sends it to a database (PostgreSQL) which then processes it and creates some entities. What concerns me is that number of fields in received JSON can be huge like

```
{
  "a":1,
  "b": 2,
  ...
}
```

And it potentially may dramatically affect the performance of database. Is there a ready solution / package to settle this issue, because I don't want to write custom `json.Unmarshaler`?

Comment: Yes, validate the input before writing it to the database. This is custom logic, you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: As of 1.15 Go has a [limit on the depth of JSON structures](https://golang.org/doc/go1.15#encoding/json), but to limit the number of fields in an object you have to write your own code. If parsing an object into a possibly huge map is a concern you have to [decode individual tokens](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Token) and abort at some point. It's far easier to [limit the input size](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#MaxBytesReader), though, which naturally puts an upper bound on the map size too.

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much for straight answer to straight question, I appreciate that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a check constraint like this:

```
CHECK (cardinality(json_object_keys(jsoncol)) <= 30)
```

That will make sure that there are no more than 30 top-level entries. Of course each of these entries could contain nested, potentially large values, but if your JSONs look like in the question, it would be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

> [I]s there a way or solution to settle this issue?

Yes. You have to check the size and abort if too big.
This can be done while reading the request, while
unmarshaling the JSON or before putting the data into
the database. All variants involve prgramming.

Comment: The point was that user may send json with short field names and values which may result in not too big json but number of fields may be more than I expect them to be.

Comment: @thisismamatto Then you cannot limit on the request level but have to limit at the JSON processing  level or at the database insert level. Both just need to be _done_ by _you_, this won't happen _magically_ .